# How can I loop over this data of nested objects?

Tags: javascript, fetch

[image]

I want to display the filters.label on the DOM. I've tried multiple loops with multiple combinations with no success.

This is a fetch call and I have to loop over the response.json().

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Do NOT post just pictures of code

Comment: looks like `const labels = data.data.collectionByHandle.products.filters.map(({label})  => label)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```js
    const filters = response.data.collectionByHandle.products.filters;
    for (var filter of filters) {
        // Your code here
    }
```